# C++ Game countdown timer

Tags: c++, windows-7, timer, countdown

I would like to ask how can I make a console game when I need the user to input some string within a period of time? (*I've tried to use `Sleep` function but it will make the screen freeze for a period of time which I don't want to*)

Example : A Pop Quiz

Comment: What have your tried? IMHO your question is not really clear at all. By the way there is a special site for [gamedev.SE].

Comment: Is your question equivalent to: "In a C++ console based program, how can I acquire a string as user input within a certan time period?"?

Comment: I mean, the answer to this question may solve your problem?

Comment: I'm planning to use Sleep function but it will freeze the input of the user at the same time. So I wanted to ask if it is possible to do realtime whether they're typing or not but the countdown still running.

Comment: I guess you'll need to use multithreading either directly with some threading library like **pthread** or indirectly with some library more specific to this. For now, try to reformulate your question in a more specific way or you may get more negative votes and your question will not be seen by many more people.

Comment: I'm still new to C++ and I haven't got the material to pthread. It's a college semester project.

Comment: Add more detail to what OS you are using, compiler and IDE. That'll help people to help you.

Comment: Edited on the main question :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you actually tried using Sleep? Even if your program is stopped, the standard input may store the user input. When your program continue to execute, it will get the input stored on stdin. Dirty but functional... And, for what you've said about pthread, maybe that's what your teacher might be expecting you to do.

Comment: I tried, but I used gets() for input function but what I mean is I can see what I typed, my teacher just care about the linked list implementation. Because my material haven't got into threading yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done without multithreading (A very simple version of a timer)

You can try to write something like this and modify it to serve your needs:

*Please note that the code is not complete. You need to edit it so it match your needs. However, this should give you an idea.*

```
int main() 
{   
   time_t begin, end;
   char input;
   bool flag = true;
   begin = time();
   while (flag) 
   {
      if(kbhit()) 
         ch = getch();
      end = time();
      if(difftime(end, begin) > NEEDED_TIME_IN_SECONDS) 
        flag = false;  //The user didn't enter it in within the wanted period of time
    }
}
```

Some documentations:

- **double difftime(time_t time2, time_t time1)**
  Return difference between two times
  Calculates the difference in seconds between time1 and time2.
- **getch()** Prompts the user to press a character and that character is not printed on screen.
- **kbhit()** It returns a non-zero integer if a key is in the keyboard buffer. It will not wait for a key to be pressed.

Comment: `<time.h>` and `<conio.h>` (for `C++` you can use `<ctime>` but I'm not sure what library corresponds to `<conio.h>` in `C++`)

Comment: alright, tried this one :) this one works for a while, right now I'm figuring how can I view the time remaining without deleting the input of the user at the same time.

Comment: This seems like it will spin CPU, I'd add a small sleep in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you use windows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define KB_UP 72
#define KB_DOWN 80
#define KB_LEFT 75
#define KB_RIGHT 77
#define KB_ESCAPE 27
#define KB_F8 66
#define KB_ENTER 13

unsigned int x_hours=0;
unsigned int x_minutes=0;
unsigned int x_seconds=0;
unsigned int x_milliseconds=0;
unsigned int totaltime=0,count_down_time_in_secs=0,time_left=0;
clock_t x_startTime,x_countTime;
int KeyBoard_code,input_count=0;
int caret_x=0,caret_y=0;
char keyboard_buffer[100]={' '};
char answer_buffer[100]={' '};
char correct_answer[ ]="foo bar";

int is_from_keyboard(int ch);
void  start_timer();
void  delta_time_update_timer();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void clrscr(void);
void setcolor(WORD color); 
void keyboard_input();

int main ()
{

    count_down_time_in_secs= 4;  // 1 minute is 60sec (60x1min), 1 hour is 3600 (60x60min)

    start_timer();
    delta_time_update_timer();

    gotoxy(1 , 2);  
    printf( "\nWhat is the answer to the  bla bla of bla bla?  ");
    gotoxy(1,5);printf( "Answer? >");


    while (time_left>0) 
    {
        keyboard_input();
        delta_time_update_timer();
    }

    gotoxy(1 , 12);
    printf( "\n\n\nTime's out\n\n\n");

return 0;
}



void  start_timer()
{
    x_startTime=clock();  // start clock
}

void  delta_time_update_timer()
{
    x_countTime=clock(); // update timer difference
    x_milliseconds=x_countTime-x_startTime;
    x_seconds=(x_milliseconds/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))-(x_minutes*60);
    x_minutes=(x_milliseconds/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC))/60;
    x_hours=x_minutes/60;
    time_left=count_down_time_in_secs-x_seconds;   // update timer


        gotoxy(1 , 1);
        printf( "\nYou have %d seconds left  ",time_left,count_down_time_in_secs);
        gotoxy(1,5);

}


void keyboard_input()
{
    if (kbhit())
      {
            KeyBoard_code = getch();

            caret_x++;
            gotoxy(10+caret_x,5+caret_y);
            printf( "%c",KeyBoard_code);
            input_count++;
            keyboard_buffer[input_count]=(char)KeyBoard_code;


            switch (KeyBoard_code)
            {

                case KB_ESCAPE:


                break;

                case KB_ENTER:

                    memcpy(answer_buffer, keyboard_buffer,sizeof(keyboard_buffer));

                    gotoxy(1 ,7);
                    printf( "Your answer is  %s ",answer_buffer);   


                    gotoxy(1,5);printf( "Answer? >              ");
                    gotoxy(1 ,9);
                    printf( "The correct answer is %s ", correct_answer);
                    caret_x=0;
                    input_count=0;
                    start_timer();
                    count_down_time_in_secs= 7;
                    delta_time_update_timer();
                    memset(keyboard_buffer,32,sizeof(keyboard_buffer));
                    memset(answer_buffer,32,sizeof(answer_buffer));

                break;

                case KB_LEFT:

                break;



                case KB_RIGHT:

                  break;

                case KB_UP:

                break;

                case KB_DOWN:

                break;

            }        

      }

}


void setcolor(WORD color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}


void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
  static HANDLE hStdout = NULL;
  COORD coord;

  coord.X = x;
  coord.Y = y;

  if(!hStdout)
  {
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  }

  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout,coord);
}


void clrscr(void)
{
  static HANDLE hStdout = NULL;      
  static CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  const COORD startCoords = {0,0};   
  DWORD dummy;

  if(!hStdout)               
  {
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout,&csbi);
  }

  FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdout,
                             ' ',
                             csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y,
                             startCoords,
                             &dummy);    
  gotoxy(0,0);
}



int is_from_keyboard(int ch)
{

    if ( ch>=31 && ch<128) return 1;
    else return -1;

}
```